# Sencha navigation bar issue

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am having problem on navigation bar in sencha :
 My code flow is :
1.login page ->click on login button opens one list 
2.on click on list items navigate to next page.
Which is ok.

but while getting back I get navigation bar on login page also wich I dont want.

Please, suggest me the proper way which should I follow.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the [Ext.navigation.View](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.navigation.View) or did you add a title bar manually? If so your login page a part of the navigation view or do you add the navigation view on top of it?

Comment: create separate view for login. Don't host it inside navigation view. Host the list in NavigationView. Then on list tap, push new view inside navigation view. That way, you won't be able to get back to login view as it was never part of navigation view. If you want titlebar or toolbar for login view as well, create it inside login view itself using toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Hide your navigation bar in activate:{}method of login page getnavigationbar.hide();